# Cannot convert value of type 'Array[String]' to expected argument type 'Set<String>'

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift, I have a function that I am passing an array to, and then using that array in another function.  I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Array[String]' to expected argument type 'Set<String>'

```
@objc func getProductInfo(productIDs: Array<String>) -> Void {
    print(productIDs) //this works with correct data

    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(productIDs) { result in

    ...
```

The rest works, and is tested when I pass in a regular array of `["Monthly", "Yearly", "etc..."]`.

Comment: What does the declaration of `SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo()` look like?

Comment: @RemyLebeau its a function that accepts an array of product ids. When I have the array ["Monthly","Yearly"] hard typed in it works no problem. Trying to make it dynamic passing an array through my app.

Comment: that is not what I asked. What is the **actual** declaration of `retrieveProductsInfo()`?  Clearly it expects something other than what you are giving it, or else you wouldn't be getting the error.

Comment: `func getProductInfo(productIDs: Set<String>`

Comment: @LeoDabus You are the best. I can accept you answer if you'd like to "answer the question". Mind explaining why Set was the right answer? Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change you method parameter type. SwiftyStoreKit method is expecting a String Set. Your method declaration should be:

```
func getProductInfo(productIDs: Set<String>)
```

Answer (score 2):

`["Monthly", "Yearly", "etc..."]` is not an array, it's an array literal. Set can be implicitly initialized with an array literal.

```
let ayeSet: Set<String> = ["a"] // Compiles
```

But, it cannot be implicitly initialized with an array.

```
let bees: Array<String> = ["b"]
let beeSet: Set<String> = bees // Causes Compiler Error
```

However, if you explicitly initialize it, then it will work.

```
let sees: Array<String> = ["c"]
let seeSet: Set<String> = Set(sees) // Compiles
```

So, in your example explicitly initialization should work.

```
@objc func getProductInfo(productIDs: Array<String>) -> Void {
    print(productIDs) //this works with correct data

    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(Set(productIDs)) { result in

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I've face the issue using the same lib.
This should work
`SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo(Set(productIDs))`